# How do I build a list of the same length as a string for my hangman game?

Tags: python, list

I'm writing a hangman game and can't figure out how to account for words of varying lengths, and my code doesn't seem to work.

Here are the steps:

1. A word is randomly selected from a list of strings
2. A board is built resembling `['_','_','_','_','_','_']`
3. The user guesses a letter
4. Replace the board with any matches in the word based on the input
5. End the game when the turns are up or the letter has been found

---

```
word = random.choice(i)
guesses = 0
turns = 11
a = [['_']*len(word)]
print(a)

print ( word)
while turns > 0:
  letter = input('Enter a letter:')
  for i in range (0, 6):
      if word[0][i] == letter:
          a[0][i] = letter
          print(a)

  if a == word:
      turns -= 1
      print("You won. ")
  else :
      turns -= 1
```

Comment: Are you telling us your program does work for 6 letter words, or not for them either?

Answer (score 2):

You need to loop through the entire length of `word`, instead of only `6` letters:

`for i in range (0, len(word)):`

Don't put `a` inside of a list, to get your desired format:

```
a = ['_']*len(word)
print(a) # ['_','_','_','_','_','_']
```

In your loop you should just access `i` directly

```
if word[i] == letter:
    a[i] = letter
```

Check that the game is over by joining the list of letters together into a string:

```
print(''.join(['h', 'i']) # 'hi'

if ''.join(a) == word:
```

If they won, `break` out of the while loop:

```
print("You won. ")
break
```

For style, add a space after the input prompt:

```
letter = input('Enter a letter: ')
```

Also, remove the `guesses` variable if you aren't using it. And don't `print(word)` (once you're done debugging).

---

NOTE: This assumes that `word` is a string, not a list of strings. I believe this is a better implementation.

Comment: I don't think the a==word comparison works here (just tried it). I think perhaps better to either check all the '-' are gone or even better, track the number of correct letters and compare to the length of the word.

Comment: also, when the person won you would want to set turns=0 to avoid asking for more letters

Answer (score 1):

A working example:

```
word = "dead"
guesses = 0
turns = 11
a = ["_" for i in range(0,len(word))]
print(a)

print (word)
while turns > 0:
    letter = input('Enter a letter:')
    for i in range (0, len(word)):
        if word[i] == letter:
            a[i] = letter
    print(a)

    if "".join(a) == word:
        print("You won.")
        break
    turns -= 1
```

Comment: I like how you print the word as guessed once per turn rather than for each letter. The variable guesses is unused.

Comment: I did not know how it was meant to be used: its usage did not feature in the original question :)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @JBallin , 
but instead of

```
for i in range (0, len(word)):
```

you can use

```
for index,ch in enumerate(word):
```

where index is from 0 to length of the word, and ch is the character itself